# Correct way to return string reference in getter

Tags: c++, syntax, getter-setter

I have a class with a string attribute, and my getters have to return string& values for those attributes.

The only way I managed to do it without getting errors is like this :

```
inline string& Class::getStringAttribute() const{
    static string dup = stringAttribute;
    return dup;
}
```

What is the correct way to write a getter returning a string reference of a private string attribute in C++ ?

Doing it like this :

```
inline string& Class::getStringAttribute() const{
    return stringAttribute;
}
```

Gets me this error :

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’
```

Comment: The usual way would be `return stringAttribute;`. If you get errors you need to include the full text of the error messages in your question.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've tried it, but I had this error : 
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’

Comment: Nice nickname french guy :D

Comment: Make them return `string`. Returning a reference is nearly always an error.

Comment: If you want to return a modifiable reference you have to have a non `const` accessor; from a `const` accessor you can only return a `const` reference to a member. You may return a *copy* in both cases (returning a plain `string` object), although if the caller wants a copy he can always make one by itself if you return a `const` reference. Whatever you do, don't do what you posted - you are returning a reference to a string that gets immediately deallocated - essentially, a dangling reference.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks a lot, I understood the issue and successfully corrected it by changing the const on my getters - in hindsight I really don't know how I got stuck on that haha

Comment: As @MatteoItalia points out (and I overlooked), the accessor function here is marked `const` but it returns a reference to non-const; those two don't go together. The usual way to do that is to have two accessors: one marked `const` that returns `const std::string&` and one not marked `const` that returns `std::string&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either return a copy or a const reference:

```
std::string get() const         { return s_; }
const std::string& get() const  { return s_; }
```

Comment: This post is two years old

Comment: People still come to read this when looking for answers to the problem. The reason I posted was the 'official' answer said to return a 'const string' which is not an ideal one. I'm clarifying it for people just learning c++.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you marked your method as `const`. Therefore, no state inside the object can change. If you return an alias to a member variable (stringAttribute, in this case) you would allow changes in the state inside the object (code outside of the object could change the string).

There are two possible solutions: either simply return a `string`, in which actually a copy of stringAttribute will be returned (and therefore the state of the object remains the same) or return a const string, in which whoever called the method cannot change the value of stringAttribute.

Also, you can remove the `const` from getStringAttribute(), but then anybody would be able to change the value of stringAttribute, which you may or may not want.